# start ghci with extensions specified in cabal configuration file

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

In my cabal file I have a bunch of language extensions enabled. Let's say I have

- TemplateHaskell
- QuasiQuotes
- CPP

Is there a way to start GHCi with these enabled automatically? instead of manually doing

> `ghci -XTemplateHaskell -XQuasiQuotes -XCPP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cabal-ghci` was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: With recent versions of cabal, use `cabal repl`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the .ghci file.  See section 2.9 in the GHC manual.

`~/.ghci`

`:set -XTemplateHaskell -XQuasiQuotes -XCPP`

Answer (score -1):

Specify the extensions in a pragma at the top of the source files:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes, CPP #-}
```

For ghc options that are not within the scope of the language pragma, you can also use the OPTIONS_GHC pragma (and you could write `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XTemplateHaskell -XQuasiQuotes -XCPP #-}` (note the lack of commas), but the language pragma is preferred where possible, as it is portable to other compilers that support the extensions).

Comment: This won't enable the extensions in the REPL itself.